# How do I configure an "immediately close program" key combination on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Title says it all. I would like to configure a key combination on Windows 7 that's the equivalent of sending "signal 9" to a program in UNIX, with no chance to intercept the command. Some programs refuse to close on Alt+F4, others pop up a prompt to save file changes or discard.

Specifications:

- Key combination that works 100% on any non-system critical process.
- The active program is required to close immediately on receiving the key combination. Its memory space and system resources are deallocated as quickly as the operating system allows, including all file and pipe handles. If the program was in the middle of writing a file, the program is cut off anyway and the file may be corrupted.
- The program isn't allowed to maneuver around the shutoff command in any way. Immediate shutoff means immediate shutoff, no excuses allowed.

I would strongly prefer a solution that doesn't need third-party tools, however those are acceptable if there is no way to do this otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

If a program is misbehaving, it may not be accepting key presses at all, so there is no way to *guarantee* that the usual Windows key combinations for termination (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) would work. Therefore, if those keystrokes do not work, you must use another tool to terminate the application.

If you want to terminate the process **immediately**, use [Windows *Taskkill*](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TaskkillAndPskill.aspx) or [SysInternals (now part of Microsoft) *PsKill*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pskill). First set up a CMD prompt (terminal, to Unix users) **in advance** with the name of the application or process ID, e.g

```
taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe
```

This would forcefully terminate *Notepad* when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the line (ergo, one keystroke).

If you do not know in advance which process is about to run amuck, then use Windows' *Task Manager* (sytem monitor, for Unix users) or [Sysinternals *Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), which can be started with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift+</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, identify the process, right-click on it and kill it. Though not a single keystroke, it is the method I prefer.

In any case, Windows uses preemptive multitasking, so (at least theoretically), killing any process should relinquish all resources.

**N.B.** Some processes *cannot* be terminated, even though the user is running as Administrator, such as a protected antivirus process. First the protection mechanism must be turned off. Others, such as Windows Services and Explorer, may restart after termination.